# Are determinants only meaningful over the field of the linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, vector-fields

Suppose I have a standard matrix $[A]^B_B$ for a linear transformation $(\mathbb{F}_2)^3 \rightarrow (\mathbb{F}_2)^3$.

Is $\det([A]_B^B) \in \mathbb{F}_2$? My intuition is yes, but I cannot find any source confirming this.

When performing arithmetic and cofactor expansion, do we take the definition of addition and multiplication as over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: Search this site and Google for "determinant over commutative ring".

Comment: Could you either link the post or provide a "yes" or "no" answer @morrowmh?

Comment: @user129393192 Wherever you encountered $\det([A]_B^B)$ there must have been a definition before that explaining what it means in that context.

Comment: No. He simply said the determinant for a 2 x 2, the cofactor expansion method, and then that the determinant being non-zero means that the transformation is an isomorphism. That is all.

Comment: @user129393192 If you take that to be the only definition you are supposed to use, the cofactor expansion method calculates the determinant as a polynomial expression in its elements. Evaluating a polynomial involves addition and multiplication of those elements. If the elements are in a certain field, then the value of the determinant will be in the same field.

Comment: Is that a proof @dxiv ? Or is this simply given by the definition?

Comment: @user129393192 That's the underlying intuition. Whether it's a proof or definition or something in between depends on the exact definition of a determinant that you use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different questions here.

> Are determinants only meaningful over the field of the linear transformation?

No, for instance they're meaningful over any field containing it.

> Is the determinant of a matrix over a field in that field?

Yes, because it's a polynomial in the entries of the matrix.

> When performing arithmetic and cofactor expansion, do we take the definition of addition and multiplication as over the field?

Yes.  You seem to have some problems with the basic definitions here.  Maybe review what a matrix is, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by the first? In class, my professor only talked about the determinant computationally.

Comment: Well, suppose you have a real linear transformation.  You can then regard this as a complex linear transformation.  This is important because e.g. it means that you have the correct number of eigenvalues (up to multiplicity, taking generalized eigenvectors).  But that's probably beyond what you've done so far.

Comment: To follow up with your reply, if it is a polynomial, how can you guarantee that it is an element of the field?

Comment: Polynomials are expressions made up from additions and multiplications, and fields are closed under addition and multiplications.

Comment: Right, but let's say you have $3x^2$ where $3 \in \mathbb{R}$, couldn't you have $x \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The determinant is made by multiplying and adding together different entries of the matrix.  If we have a real matrix, the entries of the matrix are real numbers.  If you add and multiply real numbers together you cannot get a non-real complex number as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The Leibniz formula for the determinant is given by (for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries $a_{i,j}$)
$$
\det(A)  = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \left(  \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)} \right)
$$
where

- $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n$ (the bijections $\{1,2,\cdots,n\} \to \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$)
- The sign of $\sigma \in S_n$ is denoted $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$, and is $(-1)^m$, where $m$ is the minimum number of transpositions it takes to return $\sigma$ to the identity permutation

One concludes that (since $n$ and $S_n$ are finite), interpreting $1$ and $-1$ as in the field of concern, that $\det(A)$ lies in the field as well.

---

One can also argue that, since $A$ has characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda) := \det(A - \lambda I)$, for which $\det(A) = p_A(0)$, one immediately has the desired result. If $A \in M_{n \times n}(F)$, then $p_A \in F[\lambda]$ and so $p_A(0) \in F$.

---

> When performing arithmetic and cofactor expansion, do we take the definition of addition and multiplication as over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Yes, and the same is true for other fields. This is by definition. Just as polynomial addition and multiplication in $F[x]$ is defined by operations in $F$ on the coefficients, the same is true for matrices and their operations over $F$.